# Como exibir um menu dropdown de um botão dentro de uma div com overflow: hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com o seguinte problema:

ao clicar no botão de dropdown que esta dentro de uma div com propriedade overflow: hidden ele abre, mas fica cortado. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="out_element">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Ação <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algo a mais aqui</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link separador</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="out_element">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Ação <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algo a mais aqui</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link separador</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="out_element">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Ação <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algo a mais aqui</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link separador</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="out_element">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Ação <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algo a mais aqui</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link separador</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="out_element">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            Ação <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Algo a mais aqui</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link separador</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    height: 2000px;
}
.scroll{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.out_element{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.dropdown-menu{
    position:fixed;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/3/ - 
**Estrutura completa:** http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/5/

Como resolver isso?

**PS:** Estou usando bootstrap;

Comment: Não tem solução direta com CSS. Uma `div` pai com `overflow:hidden` vai sempre cortar os elementos filhos.

Comment: Entendo @Kazzkiq - Tive que usar a solução do abfurlan, deu certinho!

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço toda a estrutura de sua página, mais segue uma sugestão usando `position:fixed` para o `menu-dropdown`:

```
ul.dropdown-menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

**Exemplo:** **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/4/)**

Com jQuery você pode pegar a posição do botão clicado e atribuir ao `dropdown`

```
$('button.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
   var pos = $(this).offset(); //posição do elemento
   var alt = $(this).height(); //altura do elemento
   var w = $(window);
   //adiciona a posição que o elemento deve ficar corrigindo se houver scroll
   $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').css({"left":pos.left-  w.scrollLeft(),"top":pos.top+alt-w.scrollTop()});
});

//corrige a posição do elemento quando houver scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pos = $('.open>.dropdown-menu').siblings('button.dropdown-toggle').offset();
    var alt = $('.open>.dropdown-menu').siblings('button.dropdown-toggle').height();
    var w = $(window);
    $('.open>.dropdown-menu').css({"left":pos.left-w.scrollLeft(),"top":pos.top+alt-w.scrollTop()});
});
//para fechar qdo scroll div
$('.scroll').scroll(function(){
    $('.open>.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

**Exemplo:** **[jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/14/)**

Comment: Minha estrutura esta exatamente assim: http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/5/ e é layout responsivo amigo.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison editei a resposta e adicionei uma solução em jQuery, veja se resolve assim

Comment: é bem isso que quero.. só que faz o seguinte, rola o scroll com o dropdown aberto. Ele fica la :(

Comment: @JeffersonAlison acabei de editar o JSFiddle pq percebi isso, veja novamente http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/10/

Comment: Isso aí @abfurlan, deu certinho aqui. Obrigado cara!

Comment: achei um problema.. é bem oque esta acontecendo comigo.. http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/12/ - de um scroll e depois clica ou clica e depois de um scroll pra ver oque acontece :(

Comment: @JeffersonAlison você tem razão, é necessário corrigir a posição no scroll, veja como ficou http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/13/

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o ideal, seria sua div `tab-content` ter um `height` fixo.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo Felipe?

Comment: Eu não sei o tamanho total do seu `container` principal. Mas, eu fiz um teste.
Coloquei `height:500px` na div `tab-content`. Olhe aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/qPP4w/

Comment: Ele num tem um tamanho fixo, inclusive por que estou trabalhando com colunas e dragdrop pro usuario arrastar o elemento pra qual coluna ele quer. Dentro desse elemento esta o dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa mesmo setar como hidden? Já tentou resetar a propriedade?

`.scroll{
    overflow: inherit;
}`

[Update do seu exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/21/)